# Creating a image slideshow (media player style) using QT UI/c++

Tags: c++, image, qt, slideshow

I'm new to C++ and QT creator. I've been looking through certain tutorials and understand certain concepts, however, I'm having a hard time applying them or even knowing where to begin. Right now, I'm trying to develop **a slideshow-like UI in QT, so basically, it looks into a series of images and loops through them like a video.** Ideally **having a PLAY and a STOP button**(I've read about possibly using QTimer) so far I've only been able to implement when I press one button, the image will appear and when I press the second button, the image will clear. Any direction is appreciated.

in mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
     QMainWindow(parent),
     ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    pixmap = QPixmap("/Users/Maggie/Desktop/test/char.png");

    connect(ui->SetImagePushButton1, SIGNAL(clicked()),    this,SLOT(on_SetImagePushButton1_clicked()));
    connect(ui->SetImagePushButton2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,SLOT(on_SetImagePushButton2_clicked()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_SetImagePushButton1_clicked()
{

    ui->pictureBox->setPixmap(pixmap);

}

void MainWindow::on_SetImagePushButton2_clicked()
{
    ui->pictureBox->setPixmap(QPixmap());
}
```

in mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_SetImagePushButton1_clicked();

    void on_SetImagePushButton2_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QPixmap pixmap;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: Create qpixmap for each image.  Use qpropertyanimation to set their positions(geometry ).

Comment: You could also look at QML. It will give you more facilities to create more beautiful interface. You QDir to iterate the directories and files and do not load all images into memory, you can cache only part of them.